# SwiftUI Context Menu Has Extra Scrollable Space For No Reason

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, scroll, contextmenu

I have a list of items, each with a `.contextMenu`. The menu works, but for some reason it is scrollable and has extra empty space above all buttons.

[image]
[image]

My simplified code. This view is a list item in a scrollable list:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            //custom view here
        }
    }
    .contextMenu {
        Button(action: {
            //action here
        }, label: {
            Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
        })
        Button(role: .destructive, action: {
            //action here
        }, label: {
            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
        })
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have `UIScrollView.appearance().contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 200, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)` for an unrelated `ScrollView`, but turns out that this affects the `contextMenu` as well. I assuming context menu is a scrollview under the hood.